# Get tempdata/ session/viewbag values in external javascript file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom AuthorizeAttribute defined in which when the user is unauthorized I am setting a tempdata["UnAuthorized"]=true. I am trying to access this value in an external javascript file which is referenced in the cshtml view, but I am uanble to get the value, it errs out
Below is the custom authorize piece

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //if not logged, it will work as normal Authorize and redirect to the Login
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData ["UnAuthorized"] = true;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error");
        }
    }
```

This is how I am trying to access it in my external .js file

```
function SetData(data) {
        var test = TempData["UnAuthorized"];
        if (!test)
        {
            $('#SetModal').html(data);
            $('#SetModal').dialog('open');
        }

    }
```

I am unable to retrieve the value stored in TempData. Please suggest. I am using asp.net mvc 5, jquery, C#

Comment: it should be var test = '@TempData["UnAuthorized"]';

Comment: I tried this and it just displays the '@TempData["UnAuthorized"]' as a string and still not displaying the value. It is displaying the string with "/" "@TempData[\"UnAuthorized\"]"

Comment: are you using this in an external js file? if yes then try it in a .cshtml file

Comment: Yes Sushil, I am using external js file

Comment: then you wont be able to access the C# code. what you can do is add the value of TempData in a hiddenField in your .cshtml page and use the value of it in the external js file. e.g. `<input type="hidden" id='hiddError' value="@TempData["UnAuthorized"]" />` and access it in ur external js file like this `var test = $('#hiddError').val();`

Comment: Not yet, Sushil I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83811/discussion-between-sushil-and-user3557236).

Comment: Razor code is not parsed in external js files. You need to declare the value in the main view - see Shoe's answer. But keep in mind that if the user refreshes the page, then `TempData` no longer exists and the value will be `null` unless you use `.Peek()` or `.Keep()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put another script in your razor view to store the value in a javascript variable and then you can use the value in your external file.

Razor:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var unauthorized = '@TempData["UnAuthorized"]';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/external.js">
}
```

External.js

```
if(unauthorized) {
    alert("unauthorized");
}
```

Comment: I have master.cshtml which refs master.js. Master.cshtml has a custom context menu,when clicked posts a ajax request which calls a controller/action method which has customauthorize attribute. Since the user is not authorized customauthorize attribute redirects to unauthorized.cshtml where I put your script code unauthorized="@Tempdata['UnAuthorized']". same master.js file in this cshtml as well. SetData code is in master.js and var unauthorized=undefined.  The flow is
master.cshtml--->customattribute--fails to atuhroize since the user does not have rights-->unauthorized.cshtml--->master.js